Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'
I am building a Blazor Server App with .Net 6.
CustomInputBase.razor file -
@inherits CustomInputBase
@using System.Linq.Expressions

@if (Type == "number")
{
    <InputNumber Value="@IntValue" ValueExpression="@(() => IntValue)" class="@Class" id="@Id" ValueChanged="OnIntValueChanged" />
}
else if (Type == "text")
{
    <InputText Value="@StringValue" ValueExpression="@(() => StringValue)" class="@Class" id="@Id" ValueChanged="OnStringValueChanged" />
}

And this is the CustomInputBase.cs file
public class CustomInputBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public string Type { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int IntValue { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> IntValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string StringValue { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> StringValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Class { get; set; } = "form-control";
 
    protected async Task OnIntValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        IntValue = newValue;
        await IntValueChanged.InvokeAsync(IntValue);
    }
 
    protected async Task OnStringValueChanged(string newValue)
    {
        StringValue = newValue;
        await StringValueChanged.InvokeAsync(StringValue);
    }
}

I am getting the error here ValueChanged="OnIntValueChanged". But OnStringValueChanged is not showing any errors.
How to solve the error?

"with  .Net 6" - just saying: you should consider moving on to 8. Winter is coming. Doesn't solve your problem, though.

If you swap the order of the code (first String, then int) in the razor file, do you get the error on the string version instead? If so, then both are equally problematic just the first hides the second.

@Fildor the requirement is to use Blazor Server App, so I have to use .Net 6. And also the error does not depend on order of the code

Ähm if that feature have been removed from Net8 (i think it isn't) it would be advisable to not use it and not use an older framework.

" the requirement is to use Blazor Server App, so I have to use .Net 6." - Doesn't seem impossible, though -> https://jonhilton.net/blazor-net8-migration/ but you do you, it was just a sidenote, because 6 goes out of service soon. Let's focus on the problem again.

I don't see an obvious difference between the two. But I would expect to see one if one leads to error and the other doesn't. I don't expect string vs int to be the problem ...

Side note: you shouldn't do IntValue = newValue;. See Avoid overwriting parameters in ASP.NET Core Blazor

Blazor/Razor has a problem detecting the type from inheritance.
